# Battleship UI: GameSheet

Tags: object-oriented, vba, excel

In the [previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/202851/23788) I presented the MVC architecture, but all we saw of the *View* was the pretty bits. From the outside everything looks innocently pretty:

[image: Battleship game in progress]

The guts of the worksheet's code-behind is a bit more... chaotic. Maybe not *chaotic-evil*, but chaotic nonetheless, despite the fact that it's really doing nothing more than exposing methods for the `GridViewAdapter` to interfact with, and handful of events for the `GridViewAdapter` to handle & relay to the game controller... I find there's too much code in there.

The UI involves a rather large number of named shapes (some clickable and thus attached to a sheet-local macro), so a lot of that code is just named (often indexed) properties that return a specific shape. The various shapes include the "player" buttons you click to pick your grid and opponent, the "fleet status" box, the ship pictures in it, and each individual "X" marker carefully positioned to cover each ship's peg holes; then there's a gigantic "HIT!", "MISS" and "SUNK" shape on each grid, and two "Game Over" shapes per grid (one winning, one losing), and in AI vs AI games there's an "acquired targets" box under each grid to show each player's enemy ships, with an "X" marker to mark sunken targets. Oh and then there's an "information" and "error" box with a clickable OK button to display various messages.

[image: game screen with all shapes visible]

The grid cells contain a hidden numeric value, and the white/red dots (and ships' preview/confirmed/illegal positions) are achieved using a custom conditional formatting:

[image: custom conditional formatting configuration]

These values correspond to the `GridState` enum values.

All feedback & cleanup ideas are welcome!

```
'@Folder("Battleship.View.Worksheet")
Option Explicit

Private Const InfoBoxMessage As String = _
    "ENEMY FLEET DETECTED" & vbNewLine & _
    "ALL SYSTEMS READY" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "DOUBLE CLICK IN THE ENEMY GRID TO FIRE A MISSILE." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "FIND AND DESTROY ALL ENEMY SHIPS BEFORE THEY DESTROY YOUR OWN FLEET!"

Private Const InfoBoxPlaceShips As String = _
    "FLEET DEPLOYMENT" & vbNewLine & _
    "ACTION REQUIRED: DEPLOY %SHIP%" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    " -CLICK TO PREVIEW" & vbNewLine & _
    " -RIGHT CLICK TO ROTATE" & vbNewLine & _
    " -DOUBLE CLICK TO CONFIRM" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

Private Const ErrorBoxInvalidPosition As String = _
    "FLEET DEPLOYMENT" & vbNewLine & _
    "SYSTEM ERROR" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    " -SHIPS CANNOT OVERLAP." & vbNewLine & _
    " -SHIPS MUST BE ENTIRELY WITHIN THE GRID." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "DEPLOY SHIP TO ANOTHER POSITION."

Private Const ErrorBoxInvalidKnownAttackPosition As String = _
    "TARGETING SYSTEM" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "SPECIFIED GRID LOCATION IS ALREADY IN A KNOWN STATE." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "NEW VALID COORDINATES REQUIRED."

Private previousMode As ViewMode
Private Mode As ViewMode

Private Random As IRandomizer

Public Event CreatePlayer(ByVal gridId As Byte, ByVal pt As PlayerType, ByVal difficulty As AIDifficulty)
Public Event SelectionChange(ByVal gridId As Byte, ByVal position As IGridCoord, ByVal Mode As ViewMode)
Public Event RightClick(ByVal gridId As Byte, ByVal position As IGridCoord, ByVal Mode As ViewMode)
Public Event DoubleClick(ByVal gridId As Byte, ByVal position As IGridCoord, ByVal Mode As ViewMode)

Public Sub OnNewGame()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Mode = NewGame
    ClearGrid 1
    ClearGrid 2
    LockGrids
    HideAllShapes
    ShowShapes HumanPlayerButton(1), _
               AIPlayerButton(1, RandomAI), _
               AIPlayerButton(1, FairplayAI), _
               AIPlayerButton(1, MercilessAI), _
               HumanPlayerButton(2), _
               AIPlayerButton(2, RandomAI), _
               AIPlayerButton(2, FairplayAI), _
               AIPlayerButton(2, MercilessAI)
    Me.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Set Random = New GameRandomizer
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Dim gridId As Byte
    Dim position As IGridCoord
    Set position = RangeToGridCoord(target, gridId)
    RaiseEvent DoubleClick(gridId, position, Mode)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    If Mode = FleetPosition Then
        Dim gridId As Byte
        Dim position As IGridCoord
        Set position = RangeToGridCoord(target, gridId)
        RaiseEvent RightClick(gridId, position, Mode)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim gridId As Byte
    Dim position As IGridCoord
    Set position = RangeToGridCoord(target, gridId)
    If Not position Is Nothing Then
        Me.Unprotect
        CurrentSelectionGrid(gridId).value = position.ToA1String
        CurrentSelectionGrid(IIf(gridId = 1, 2, 1)).value = Empty
        Me.Protect
        Me.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
        RaiseEvent SelectionChange(gridId, position, Mode)
    End If
End Sub

Public Function RangeToGridCoord(ByVal target As Range, ByRef gridId As Byte) As IGridCoord
    If target.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
    For gridId = 1 To 2
        With PlayerGrid(gridId)
            If Not Intersect(.Cells, target) Is Nothing Then
                Set RangeToGridCoord = _
                    GridCoord.Create(xPosition:=target.Column - .Column + 1, _
                                     yPosition:=target.Row - .Row + 1)
                Exit Function
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Function

Public Function GridCoordToRange(ByVal gridId As Byte, ByVal position As IGridCoord) As Range
    With PlayerGrid(gridId)
        Set GridCoordToRange = .Cells(position.Y, position.X)
    End With
End Function

Public Sub ClearGrid(ByVal gridId As Byte)
    Me.Unprotect
    PlayerGrid(gridId).value = Empty
    Me.Protect
    Me.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub

Public Sub LockGrids()
    Me.Unprotect
    PlayerGrid(1).Locked = True
    PlayerGrid(2).Locked = True
    Me.Protect
    Me.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub

Public Sub UnlockGrid(ByVal gridId As Byte)
    Me.Unprotect
    PlayerGrid(gridId).Locked = False
    PlayerGrid(IIf(gridId = 1, 2, 1)).Locked = True
    Me.Protect
    Me.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub

Public Sub LockGrid(ByVal gridId As Byte)
    Me.Unprotect
    PlayerGrid(gridId).Locked = True
    PlayerGrid(IIf(gridId = 1, 2, 1)).Locked = False
    Me.Protect
    Me.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub

Private Property Get PlayerGrid(ByVal gridId As Byte) As Range
    Set PlayerGrid = Me.Names("PlayerGrid" & gridId).RefersToRange
End Property

Private Property Get CurrentSelectionGrid(ByVal gridId As Byte) As Range
    Set CurrentSelectionGrid = Me.Names("CurrentSelectionGrid" & gridId).RefersToRange
End Property

Private Property Get TitleLabel() As Shape
    Set TitleLabel = Me.Shapes("Title")
End Property

Private Property Get MissLabel(ByVal gridId As Byte) As Shape
    Set MissLabel = Me.Shapes("MissLabelGrid" & gridId)
End Property

Private Property Get HitLabel(ByVal gridId As Byte) As Shape
    Set HitLabel = Me.Shapes("HitGrid" & gridId)
End Property

Private Property Get SunkLabel(ByVal gridId As Byte) As Shape
    Set SunkLabel = Me.Shapes("SunkGrid" & gridId)
End Property

Private Property Get GameOverWinLabel(ByVal gridId As Byte) As Shape
    Set GameOverWinLabel = Me.Shapes("GameOverWinGrid" & gridId)
End Property

Private Property Get GameOverLoseLabel(ByVal gridId As Byte) As Shape
    Set GameOverLoseLabel = Me.Shapes("GameOverLoseGrid" & gridId)
End Property

Private Property Get InformationBox() As Shape
    Set InformationBox = Me.Shapes("InformationBox")
End Property

Private Property Get ErrorBox() As Shape
    Set ErrorBox = Me.Shapes("ErrorBox")
End Property

Private Property Get FleetStatusBox() As Shape
    Set FleetStatusBox = Me.Shapes("FleetStatusBox")
End Property

Private Property Get AcquiredTargetsBox(ByVal gridId As Byte) As Shape
    Set AcquiredTargetsBox = Me.Shapes("Grid" & gridId & "TargetsBox")
End Property

Private Property Get AcquiredTargetShip(ByVal gridId As Byte, ByVal shipName As String) As Shape
    Set AcquiredTargetShip = Me.Shapes("Grid" & gridId & "Target_" & VBA.Strings.Replace(shipName, " ", vbNullString))
End Property

Private Property Get ShipHitMarker(ByVal shipName As String, ByVal index As Byte) As Shape
    Set ShipHitMarker = Me.Shapes(VBA.Strings.Replace(shipName, " ", vbNullString) & "_Hit" & index)
End Property

Private Property Get SunkTargetMarker(ByVal gridId As Byte, ByVal shipName As String) As Shape
    Set SunkTargetMarker = Me.Shapes("Grid" & gridId & "TargetSunk_" & VBA.Strings.Replace(shipName, " ", vbNullString))
End Property

Private Property Get HumanPlayerButton(ByVal gridId As Byte) As Shape
    Set HumanPlayerButton = Me.Shapes("HumanPlayer" & gridId)
End Property

Private Property Get AIPlayerButton(ByVal gridId As Byte, ByVal difficulty As AIDifficulty) As Shape
    Select Case difficulty
        Case AIDifficulty.RandomAI
            Set AIPlayerButton = Me.Shapes("RandomAIPlayer" & gridId)
        Case AIDifficulty.FairplayAI
            Set AIPlayerButton = Me.Shapes("FairPlayAIPlayer" & gridId)
        Case AIDifficulty.MercilessAI
            Set AIPlayerButton = Me.Shapes("MercilessAIPlayer" & gridId)
    End Select
End Property

Private Sub HidePlayerButtons(Optional ByVal gridId As Byte)
    If gridId = 0 Then
        For gridId = 1 To 2
            HideShapes HumanPlayerButton(gridId), _
                       AIPlayerButton(gridId, RandomAI), _
                       AIPlayerButton(gridId, FairplayAI), _
                       AIPlayerButton(gridId, MercilessAI)
        Next
    Else
        HideShapes HumanPlayerButton(gridId), _
                   AIPlayerButton(gridId, RandomAI), _
                   AIPlayerButton(gridId, FairplayAI), _
                   AIPlayerButton(gridId, MercilessAI)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub OnHumanPlayer1()
    HidePlayerButtons 1
    HideShapes HumanPlayerButton(2)
    RaiseEvent CreatePlayer(1, HumanControlled, Unspecified)
End Sub

Public Sub OnHumanPlayer2()
    HidePlayerButtons 2
    HideShapes HumanPlayerButton(1)
    RaiseEvent CreatePlayer(2, HumanControlled, Unspecified)
End Sub

Public Sub OnRandomAIPlayer1()
    HidePlayerButtons 1
    RaiseEvent CreatePlayer(1, ComputerControlled, RandomAI)
End Sub

Public Sub OnRandomAIPlayer2()
    HidePlayerButtons 2
    RaiseEvent CreatePlayer(2, ComputerControlled, RandomAI)
End Sub

Public Sub OnFairPlayAIPlayer1()
    HidePlayerButtons 1
    RaiseEvent CreatePlayer(1, ComputerControlled, FairplayAI)
End Sub

Public Sub OnFairPlayAIPlayer2()
    HidePlayerButtons 2
    RaiseEvent CreatePlayer(2, ComputerControlled, FairplayAI)
End Sub

Public Sub OnMercilessAIPlayer1()
    HidePlayerButtons 1
    RaiseEvent CreatePlayer(1, ComputerControlled, MercilessAI)
End Sub

Public Sub OnMercilessAIPlayer2()
    HidePlayerButtons 2
    RaiseEvent CreatePlayer(2, ComputerControlled, MercilessAI)
End Sub

Public Sub HideInformationBox()
    InformationBox.Visible = msoFalse
    Mode = previousMode
    If Mode = player1 Then
        UnlockGrid 2
    ElseIf Mode = player2 Then
        UnlockGrid 1
    End If
    Me.Protect
    Me.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub

Public Sub HideErrorBox()
    ErrorBox.Visible = msoFalse
    Mode = previousMode
    Me.Protect
    Me.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub

Public Sub ShowInfoBeginDeployShip(ByVal shipName As String)
    Mode = FleetPosition
    ShowFleetStatus
    ShowInformation Replace(InfoBoxPlaceShips, "%SHIP%", UCase$(shipName))
End Sub

Public Sub ShowInfoBeginAttackPhase()
    Mode = player1
    ShowInformation InfoBoxMessage
End Sub

Public Sub ShowErrorKnownPositionAttack()
    ShowError ErrorBoxInvalidKnownAttackPosition
End Sub

Public Sub RefreshGrid(ByVal grid As PlayerGrid)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Me.Unprotect
    PlayerGrid(grid.gridId).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(grid.StateArray)
    Me.Protect
    Me.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub ShowInformation(ByVal message As String)
    Me.Unprotect
    With InformationBox

        With .GroupItems("InformationBoxBackground")
            With .TextFrame
                .Characters.Delete
                .Characters.Text = vbNewLine & message
                .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignTop
                .VerticalOverflow = xlOartVerticalOverflowEllipsis
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
            End With
        End With

        .Visible = msoTrue
    End With
    previousMode = Mode
    Mode = MessageShown
    Me.Protect
    Me.EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
End Sub

Public Sub ShowError(ByVal message As String)
    Me.Unprotect
    With ErrorBox

        With .GroupItems("ErrorBoxBackground")
            With .TextFrame
                .Characters.Delete
                .Characters.Text = vbNewLine & message
                .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignTop
                .VerticalOverflow = xlOartVerticalOverflowEllipsis
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
            End With
        End With

        .Visible = msoTrue
    End With
    previousMode = Mode
    Mode = MessageShown
    Me.Protect
    Me.EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
End Sub

Public Sub HideAllShapes()
    Me.Unprotect
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    HideFleetStatus
    HideAcquiredTargetBoxes
    HideShapes InformationBox, ErrorBox
    Dim grid As Byte
    For grid = 1 To 2
        HideShapes HitLabel(grid), _
                   SunkLabel(grid), _
                   MissLabel(grid), _
                   MissLabel(grid), _
                   HumanPlayerButton(grid), _
                   AIPlayerButton(grid, RandomAI), _
                   AIPlayerButton(grid, FairplayAI), _
                   AIPlayerButton(grid, MercilessAI), _
                   GameOverWinLabel(grid), _
                   GameOverLoseLabel(grid), _
                   AcquiredTargetsBox(grid)
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Me.Protect
End Sub

Public Sub ShowAllShapes()
'for debugging
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ShowFleetStatus
    ShowAcquiredTargetBoxes
    ShowShapes InformationBox, ErrorBox
    Dim grid As Byte
    For grid = 1 To 2
        ShowShapes HitLabel(grid), _
                   SunkLabel(grid), _
                   MissLabel(grid), _
                   MissLabel(grid), _
                   HumanPlayerButton(grid), _
                   AIPlayerButton(grid, RandomAI), _
                   AIPlayerButton(grid, FairplayAI), _
                   AIPlayerButton(grid, MercilessAI), _
                   GameOverWinLabel(grid), _
                   GameOverLoseLabel(grid), _
                   AcquiredTargetsBox(grid)

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub HideFleetStatus()

    HideShapes FleetStatusBox

    Dim shipFleet As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set shipFleet = Ship.Fleet

    Dim Names As Variant
    Names = shipFleet.Keys

    Dim sizes As Variant
    sizes = shipFleet.Items

    Dim currentName As Byte
    For currentName = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)
        HideShipStatus Names(currentName)
        Dim position As Byte
        For position = 1 To sizes(currentName)
            HideShapes ShipHitMarker(Names(currentName), position)
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub HideAcquiredTargetBoxes()

    Dim shipFleet As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set shipFleet = Ship.Fleet

    Dim Names As Variant
    Names = shipFleet.Keys

    Dim gridId As Byte
    For gridId = 1 To 2
        AcquiredTargetsBox(gridId).Visible = msoFalse
        Dim currentName As Byte
        For currentName = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)
            AcquiredTargetShip(gridId, Names(currentName)).Visible = msoFalse
            SunkTargetMarker(gridId, Names(currentName)).Visible = msoFalse
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ShowAcquiredTargetBoxes()

    Dim shipFleet As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set shipFleet = Ship.Fleet

    Dim Names As Variant
    Names = shipFleet.Keys

    Dim gridId As Byte
    For gridId = 1 To 2
        AcquiredTargetsBox(gridId).Visible = msoTrue
        Dim currentName As Byte
        For currentName = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)
            AcquiredTargetShip(gridId, Names(currentName)).Visible = msoTrue
            SunkTargetMarker(gridId, Names(currentName)).Visible = msoTrue
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub ShowAcquiredTarget(ByVal gridId As Byte, ByVal shipName As String, Optional ByVal sunken As Boolean = False)
    AcquiredTargetsBox(gridId).Visible = msoTrue
    AcquiredTargetShip(gridId, shipName).Visible = msoTrue
    SunkTargetMarker(gridId, shipName).Visible = IIf(sunken, msoTrue, msoFalse)
End Sub

Private Sub ShowFleetStatus()
    FleetStatusBox.Visible = msoTrue
End Sub

Private Sub HideShipStatus(ByVal shipName As String)
    Me.Shapes("FleetStatus_" & VBA.Strings.Replace(shipName, " ", vbNullString)).Visible = msoFalse
End Sub

Private Sub ShowShipStatus(ByVal shipName As String)
    Me.Shapes("FleetStatus_" & VBA.Strings.Replace(shipName, " ", vbNullString)).Visible = msoTrue
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateShipStatus(ByVal player As IPlayer, ByVal hitShip As IShip)

    Dim positions As Variant
    positions = hitShip.StateArray

    Dim currentPosition As Byte, currentMarker As Byte
    For currentPosition = LBound(positions) To UBound(positions)
        currentMarker = currentMarker + 1
        If positions(currentPosition) Then
            If player.PlayerType = HumanControlled Then
                ShipHitMarker(hitShip.Name, currentMarker).Visible = msoTrue
            Else
                'todo: update AI player targets
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub ShowAnimationMiss(ByVal gridId As Byte)
    FlashShape MissLabel(gridId), IIf(Random.NextSingle < 0.75, 1, IIf(Random.NextSingle < 0.75, 2, 3)), 10
End Sub

Public Sub ShowAnimationHit(ByVal gridId As Byte)
    FlashShape HitLabel(gridId), IIf(Random.NextSingle < 0.75, 1, IIf(Random.NextSingle < 0.75, 2, 3))
End Sub

Public Sub ShowAnimationSunk(ByVal gridId As Byte)
    FlashShape SunkLabel(gridId), IIf(Random.NextSingle < 0.75, 2, 4), 12
End Sub

Public Sub ShowAnimationVictory(ByVal gridId As Byte)
    GameOverWinLabel(gridId).Visible = msoTrue
    Mode = GameOver
End Sub

Public Sub ShowAnimationDefeat(ByVal gridId As Byte)
    FlashShape GameOverLoseLabel(gridId), 4
    GameOverLoseLabel(gridId).Visible = msoTrue
    Mode = GameOver
End Sub

Public Sub PreviewShipPosition(ByVal player As IPlayer, ByVal newShip As IShip)
    RefreshGrid player.PlayGrid
    Me.Unprotect
    With PlayerGrid(player.PlayGrid.gridId) _
        .Cells(1, 1) _
        .Offset(newShip.GridPosition.Y - 1, newShip.GridPosition.X - 1) _
        .Resize(RowSize:=IIf(newShip.Orientation = Vertical, newShip.Size, 1), _
                ColumnSize:=IIf(newShip.Orientation = Horizontal, newShip.Size, 1))

        .value = GridState.PreviewShipPosition

    End With

    Dim intersecting As GridCoord
    Set intersecting = player.PlayGrid.IntersectsAny(newShip.GridPosition, newShip.Orientation, newShip.Size)
    If Not intersecting Is Nothing Then
        PlayerGrid(player.PlayGrid.gridId).Cells(intersecting.Y, intersecting.X).value = GridState.InvalidPosition
    End If
    Me.Protect
    Me.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub

Public Sub ConfirmShipPosition(ByVal player As IPlayer, ByVal newShip As IShip, ByRef confirmed As Boolean)
    If player.PlayGrid.CanAddShip(newShip.GridPosition, newShip.Orientation, newShip.Size) Then
        player.PlayGrid.AddShip newShip
        RefreshGrid player.PlayGrid
        ShowShipStatus newShip.Name
        confirmed = True
    Else
        ShowError ErrorBoxInvalidPosition
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ShowShapes(ParamArray objects() As Variant)
    Win32API.ScreenUpdate False
    Dim i As Long, current As Shape
    For i = LBound(objects) To UBound(objects)
        Set current = objects(i)
        current.Visible = msoTrue
    Next
    Win32API.ScreenUpdate True
End Sub

Public Sub HideShapes(ParamArray objects() As Variant)
    Win32API.ScreenUpdate False
    Dim i As Long, current As Shape
    For i = LBound(objects) To UBound(objects)
        Set current = objects(i)
        current.Visible = msoFalse
    Next
    Win32API.ScreenUpdate True
End Sub

Private Sub FlashShape(ByVal target As Shape, ByVal flashes As Long, Optional ByVal Delay As Long = 8)

    Me.Unprotect
    target.Rotation = -10 + (Random.NextSingle * 20)
    'Target.Top = Target.Top - 10 + (random.NextSingle * 20)
    'Target.Left = Target.Left - 10 + (random.NextSingle * 20)

    ShowShapes target
    Sleep Delay * 10

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To flashes - 1

        ShowShapes target
        Sleep Delay * 1.5

        HideShapes target
        Sleep Delay * 0.75

    Next

    ShowShapes target
    Sleep Delay * 20

    HideShapes target
    Me.Protect

End Sub
```

---

Update: The full code is now [on GitHub](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Battleship)!

Comment: Again, don't have time to run a  proper review answer. A quick thought for the `Public Sub On[]PlayerX` series could be collapsed into a single sub with two parameters (P1, P2 tag), looping twice over a `Select Case` and hiding/raising events as required. But I couldn't quickly see where they were called, so I may be missing something.

Comment: The other thing that struck me was your use of shapes *alongside* the conditional formatting. If you simply fill the grid with the right number, the system will put the right shape in there and you would not have to manage and manipulate shapes. Again, I may be missing something here but that is because I have not spent the time to look at the code in context.

Comment: Forgot to mention, `OnXxxx` public parameterless procedures are macros attached to shapes. It's the user clicking a button, basically. So nope, can't collapse =)

Comment: The grid is updated by dumping the gridstate array into the worksheet; cond.formatting does the rest - the named shapes are the rest of the UI: the ships that appear on the right panel as you confirm them, the markers indicating their status, the HIT!, MISS, and SUNK animations, etc

Comment: @AJD the posts about the ships and AI have links to recordings I uploaded to dropbox show the game in action: it's clearer what all these shapes are when you *see* them; e.g. the "player" buttons are shown at the beginning of the game when you pick your grid and opponent.

Comment: OK - makes sense now.

Comment: I find it ironic that you name your constants using Pascal notation because you hate "All Caps" screaming at you but your constant values are in "All Caps".

Comment: @TinMan imagine if the names were all caps *on top of that*! :D

Comment: @MathieuGuindon. I knew you were going to say that.  SCREAM AT YOU LATER :=)

Comment: I will take particular exception to Pascal constants, just because I can. Then I will grumble something about consistency being more important.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I've been working on an UI for your game.  Do you mind if I post it when I'm finished?

Comment: @TinMan of course not, it was the idea all along! =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon , I am getting ready to write a post with my BattleShip UI.  How should I handle linking the files?  Would you consider adding them to your GitHub?

Comment: Of course! If you forked the project then you can make a pull request (make sure you register for Hacktoberfest! 5 PRs in any repository this month and you get a t-shirt!)

Answer (score 1):

One thing I'm confused about while reading this, is `gridId as Byte` - I assume it can only be `1` or `2` - ID of the player, unless I'm mistaken.

So in `RangeToGridCoord` you take the `gridID` *ByRef*, but *why?*

> ```
> Public Function RangeToGridCoord(ByVal target As Range, ByRef gridId As Byte) As IGridCoord
>     If target.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
>     For gridId = 1 To 2
>         With PlayerGrid(gridId)
>             If Not Intersect(.Cells, target) Is Nothing Then
>                 Set RangeToGridCoord = _
>                     GridCoord.Create(xPosition:=target.Column - .Column + 1, _
>                                      yPosition:=target.Row - .Row + 1)
>                 Exit Function
>             End If
>         End With
>     Next
> End Function
> ```

You call this function in three different worksheet events, passing a null `gridId` each time, then you make it iterate over both possibilities -

> ```
> For gridID = 1 to 2
> ```

Maybe (read: definitely) I'm missing some interactions that occur from/to different game areas or mechanics, but this alone looks unnecessary. You're converting a target to a coordinate, but only for the player whose grid intersects that target - but unless a target is more than 1 cell, it can only ever intersect 1 or 0 player grids. Maybe this has something to do with the `IGridCoord`, but from here, *on this question* I don't understand the need for the loop - either it intersects or it doesn't, assuming you pass a non-null `gridId` to the function, right?

Comment: Perhaps a better name would have been `ByRef outGridId As GridId`: given a `Range`, we don't know whether we're in grid 1 or in grid 2 until we intersect that range with the grids' range; since I don't want `IGridCoord` to have any knowledge of being in a grid, I'm returning this information as an out/ref parameter. And I agree, that `Byte` is bleeding everywhere and it's annoying; something like a `GridId` enum would fix that; `GridId.Player1`, or `GridId.Player2`.

Comment: So by design you give it a null that it evaluates to give you the Grid ID? And you do this byref because your function is otherwise returning a different result, and you want to capture this as well? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: that's correct. well except for the `null` part (you give it a `Byte` reference, i.e. a local variable to return the result into) ;-)  the idea of the function is that it returns an X,Y coordinate, given a `Range` on the game sheet - `A1` is `$S$12` in grid 2, and `$D$12` in grid 1, as far as Excel knows. But the game doesn't care for the actual range addresses.

Answer (score 1):

### The IShip Conundrum

While writing my UI for the game I ran into several problems both trying to extend the Ship class and write my own class that implements the IShip interface.

The main issue I had writing my own Ship class was that 80+ percent of the code would be copied from the OP's Ship class.  Where is the code reuse?  Since the majority of the Ship code is consists of either settings or methods that need to be present in all IShip classes, I concluded an Abstract class was needed.  This lead me to try to use the Ship class as a base class (similar the [Answer - VBA: is there something like Abstract Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21223273/9912714)
.

After I subclassed the Ship class, I tried to replace the Ships that were being passed from the Controller to the View but found that it is not possible to do.  Faced with this problem I tried to modify the Controller.

My approach to modifying the Controller was simply pass to replace the Ship factories in the Controller with a class instance that implemented IShip. I found that the Controller was dependent on the ShipKinds method of the Ship class and not the IShip interface.  ShipKinds should be added to the IShip interface.

This lead me to think deeper on the roles and interactions of the IShip, Controller, and View.  It seems that the Controller produces the IShips because the View cannot validate the IShip placement without know of the IPlayerGrid model.  Is there a use case in which  the Controller would need different versions of IShip...I don't think so.  After all the Controller is responsible for managing the flow of interactions between the Model, View and Strategies not for modifying or using the IShips.  The View, however, could definitely benefit by using custom IShip classes.  It would be really convenient to have the Ships reference labels, images, divs or whatever that are responsible for rendering them.  But is the View is the one would benefit the most from a custom IShp, why are the IShips immutable by the View?

I think a better setup would be to have the Controller request the IShips from the View for validation.  This will allow the Controller to still be validating the IShips against the Model, while allowing the View to implement whichever type of IShip that it needs.  This setup would also allow the same Controller to be used by all types of Views without modification.

At this point I decided to follow the script that was laid out by the WorksheetView class and everything fell in place nicely.  After I got my prototype working and posted it to CR, I realized that I had made it much more complicated than it needed to be.  My next prototype will probably contain 40% less VBA code.

### Random Thoughts

Having to click the `ShowInformation` between each deployment is annoying.  I would like to see this changed to a passive (non response) alert.

I would also like to see a ShipIndex property and DeploymentComplete method added to the IGridViewCommands interface.  This would facilitate repositioning ships after their positions were confirmed.

What do you think of a  <strike>MultiplayerHumanStrategy</strike> **MultiPlayer Mode**?  The idea is to store each players ship and attack position information on a worksheet.  The <strike>Strategies</strike> **game** could then take advantage of the new Co-Authoring feature to allow multiple players to play, in real-time, over a network.