# So what if the "View" in an MVC isn't a Userform, but is the Worksheet?

Tags: object-oriented, vba, excel

So I've been following the discussions around VBA as an OOP language and the applicability of various design patterns, such as MVP or MVC. Excellent postings on these topics are extremely informative and have caused me to rethink my implementation approach for my projects (past and present). Change and growth is always a good thing :)

- [What are MVP and MVC and what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/101561/4717755)
- [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)
- [Responding to Events of Dynamically added Controls](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/205263/responding-to-events-of-dynamically-added-controls)
- [VBA+OOP: What, When, and Why](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/08/29/vbaoop-what-when-why/)
- plus many of the posts here on Code Review (especially the [Battleship](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204982/web-battleship-the-unofficial-battleship-ui) implementation)

What I'm looking for is a discussion along these lines on the applicability of the MVC/MVP design pattern when then the "view" is not a userform, but is the worksheet itself. I think this is a common implementation technique for many developers, both new and experienced. This especially includes worksheets that hold the data to be manipulated and use embedded form controls. I'll contribute an example of my own approach to add to the discussion for critique and comment.

**Design Thoughts**

Most of the clean examples discussed about an MVP or MVC design pattern present the user interface as a userform. The userform is an easily accessible object with the class VBA code written largely by the developer. Controls are added, often `WithEvents`, and `Interface` classes can be designed for the userform to `Implement`. The data presented and/or used on the userform most often is derived or directly sourced from data on a worksheet. But what if the worksheet IS both the datastore and the "view with controls"?

I toyed with creating a persistent object that would be always available (`VB_PredeclaredId = True`), but discarded that idea because there already is a persistent data store: the worksheet object itself. The basic idea is an MVC design pattern.

After many different iterations, I arrived at a design where a data model is created only when needed, i.e. when activity on the worksheet occurs. The "view" aspect of the pattern is handled directly by the formatted data on the worksheet. The "controller" part of the pattern are functional `Sub` and `Function` calls tied directly to worksheet or control events.

*(The whole reason for this post and my interest in a discussion is to find out if this is a "preferred" way of achieving the goals of the application. Clearly, my approach works. But I'm always on a quest for improvement!)*

**The Application**

This is one part of an overall application that's needed to import a variety of data from external sources. The original configuration interface was set up on a worksheet with a (relatively) static number of possible entries. Each entry row is selectable and the user can click a button to bring up the file selection dialog to choose a file. Two of the fields are user-editable. (Optional access to this application in my [GitHub](https://github.com/pmtutko/ConfigureView))

[image]

*If you choose, there is a module below (`CreateProjectSheet`) that should create the "Configure" worksheet, format the "view" and create the controls. Obviously, run the top-level routine once to set up the worksheet.*

**The Code - ConfigureView Project**

The code breaks down into a combination of the data model (`ProjectsModel` with a `ProjectInfo` collection) and the "controller" code (several code modules that respond to the worksheet and control events.

[image]

Starting in the `ProjectGlobal` module, there is a set of helper functions that give quick access to relevant areas of the "view". Additionally, I've established an enumeration that provides access to the correct data column within the "view".

Module: `ProjectGlobal`

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum ProjectInfoColumns
    [_First] = 1                                 'columns numbers are relative to the anchor cell
    ProjectNumber = 1
    SelectCheckBox = 2
    DBName = 3
    FullPath = 4
    BrowseButton = 5
    FileTimestamp = 6
    SelectedCellLink = 7
    [_Last] = 7
End Enum

Public Enum ProjectApp_Errors
    NoProjectArea = vbObject + 600
    IndexOutOfBounds
End Enum

Public Const DEFAULT_PROJECT_ROWS As Long = 15
Public Const ROW_ONE_ANCHOR As String = "A3"

Public Function ConnectToModel() As ProjectsModel
    Dim anchor As Range
    Dim projectArea As Range
    Set anchor = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configure").Range(ROW_ONE_ANCHOR)
    Set projectArea = anchor.Resize(DEFAULT_PROJECT_ROWS, ProjectInfoColumns.[_Last])

    Dim pvm As ProjectsModel
    Set pvm = New ProjectsModel
    pvm.Connect projectArea
    Set ConnectToModel = pvm
End Function

Public Function ProjectEditableArea() As Range
    Dim anchor As Range
    Dim projectArea As Range
    Set anchor = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configure").Range(ROW_ONE_ANCHOR)
    Set projectArea = anchor.Resize(DEFAULT_PROJECT_ROWS, ProjectInfoColumns.[_Last])

    Set ProjectEditableArea = Application.Union(projectArea.Columns(ProjectInfoColumns.DBName), _
                                                projectArea.Columns(ProjectInfoColumns.FullPath))
End Function

Public Function ProjectSelectAllCell() As Range
    Dim anchor As Range
    Set anchor = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configure").Range(ROW_ONE_ANCHOR)
    Set ProjectSelectAllCell = anchor.Offset(-1, ProjectInfoColumns.SelectedCellLink - 1)
End Function

Public Function ProjectInfoColumnsName(ByVal index As Long) As String
    ProjectInfoColumnsName = vbNullString
    If (index >= ProjectInfoColumns.[_First]) Or _
       (index <= ProjectInfoColumns.[_Last]) Then

        Dim names() As String
        names = Split(",Name in DB,MS Excel Path,," & _
                      "MS Excel File Timestamp,,", _
                      ",", , vbTextCompare)

        ProjectInfoColumnsName = names(index - 1)
    End If
End Function

Public Function ProjectRowIndex(ByVal wsRowIndex As Long) As Long
    '--- given the worksheet row number, this returns the project
    '    index row into the group of projects
    Dim anchor As Range
    Set anchor = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configure").Range(ROW_ONE_ANCHOR)
    ProjectRowIndex = wsRowIndex - anchor.Row + 1
End Function
```

In particular, notice the `ConnectToModel` function that creates the data model giving quick and abstracted access to the underlying data. All data access should go through this model.

Class: `ProjectsModel`

```
Option Explicit

Private Type InternalData
    storage As Range
    projects As Collection    'collection of ProjectInfo objects
End Type
Private this As InternalData

Public Property Get IsConnected() As Boolean
    IsConnected = (Not this.projects Is Nothing)
End Property

Public Property Get ProjectCount() As Long
    If Not this.projects Is Nothing Then
        ProjectCount = this.projects.Count
    Else
        ProjectCount = 0
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get GetProject(ByVal index As Long) As ProjectInfo
    If Not this.projects Is Nothing Then
        If index > 0 And index <= this.projects.Count Then
            Set GetProject = this.projects(index)
        Else
            Err.Raise ProjectApp_Errors.IndexOutOfBounds, _
                      "ProjectsModel::GetProject", _
                      "Project index out of bounds"
        End If
    Else
        Set GetProject = Nothing
    End If
End Property

Public Sub Connect(ByRef projectArea As Range)
    If this.storage Is Nothing Then
        If Not projectArea Is Nothing Then
            Set this.storage = projectArea
        Else
            Err.Raise ProjectApp_Errors.NoProjectArea, _
                      "ProjectsModel::Load", _
                      "Missing project area"
        End If
    ElseIf Not this.storage = projectArea Then
        '--- we've got a new table, so dump the old one and reload
        Set this.storage = Nothing
        Set this.storage = projectArea
    End If

    Set this.projects = Nothing
    Set this.projects = New Collection

    Dim projectRow As Range
    Set projectRow = this.storage.Resize(1, ProjectInfoColumns.[_Last])

    Dim i As Long
    Dim newInfo As ProjectInfo
    For i = 1 To projectArea.Rows.Count
        Set newInfo = New ProjectInfo
        newInfo.Connect projectRow
        this.projects.Add newInfo
        Set projectRow = projectRow.Offset(1, 0)
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function GetSelectedProjects() As Collection
    Dim selectedCollection As Collection
    Dim projectRow As Variant
    For Each projectRow In this.projects
        If projectRow.IsSelected Then
            If selectedCollection Is Nothing Then
                Set selectedCollection = New Collection
            End If
            selectedCollection.Add projectRow
        End If
    Next projectRow
    Set GetSelectedProjects = selectedCollection
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

End Sub
```

There's an interesting aspect to the `ProjectInfo` class below. Because each "view" row has a checkbox (and a button), expected UX behavior would present the checkbox as "unselectable" if the row is empty of data. So each of the `ProjectInfo` objects must "connect" to the appropriate checkbox located on its row, and then enable/disable as appropriate.

Class: `ProjectInfo`

```
Option Explicit

Private Type InternalData
    projectRow As Range
    selectBox As CheckBox
End Type
Private this As InternalData

Public Property Let IsSelected(ByVal newState As Boolean)
    '--- can only be selected if there is a valid filename
    If Len(this.projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.FullPath)) > 0 Then
        this.projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.SelectedCellLink).Value = newState
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get IsSelected() As Boolean
    IsSelected = this.projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.SelectedCellLink).Value
End Property

Public Property Let NameInDB(ByVal newName As String)
    '--- disable events because this area is watched by a
    '    Worksheet_Change event
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    this.projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.DBName).Value = newName
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Property

Public Property Get NameInDB() As String
    NameInDB = this.projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.DBName).Value
End Property

Public Property Let FullPath(ByVal newPath As String)
    '--- disable events because this area is watched by a
    '    Worksheet_Change event
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Len(newPath) > 0 Then
        this.projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.FullPath).Value = newPath
        On Error GoTo TimestampError
        Me.FileTimestamp = FileDateTime(newPath)
    Else
        '--- clear all the data if the user deleted the name
        this.projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.DBName).Value = vbNullString
        this.projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.FullPath).Value = vbNullString
        this.projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.FileTimestamp).Value = vbNullString
    End If

NormalExit:
    SetCheckBoxState
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Property
TimestampError:
    If Err.Number = 53 Then
        MsgBox "The filename you entered is not valid. Please enter " & _
               "a valid filename.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
               "Error In Filename"
        this.projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.FullPath).Value = vbNullString
    End If
    GoTo NormalExit
End Property

Public Property Get FullPath() As String
    FullPath = this.projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.FullPath)
End Property

Public Property Get PathOnly() As String
    '--- returns ONLY the path part of the full path
    PathOnly = vbNullString
    If Len(Me.FullPath) = 0 Then
        Exit Property
    End If

    Dim pos1 As Long
    pos1 = InStrRev(Me.FullPath, "\", , vbTextCompare)
    If pos1 > 0 Then
        PathOnly = left$(Me.FullPath, pos1 - 1)
    Else
        PathOnly = Me.FullPath
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get Filename() As String
    '--- returns ONLY the filename part of the full path
    Filename = vbNullString
    If Len(Me.FullPath) = 0 Then
        Exit Property
    End If

    Dim pos1 As Long
    pos1 = InStrRev(Me.FullPath, "\", , vbTextCompare)
    If pos1 > 0 Then
        Filename = Right$(Me.FullPath, Len(Me.FullPath) - pos1)
    Else
        Filename = Me.FullPath
    End If
End Property

Public Property Let FileTimestamp(ByVal newDate As Date)
    this.projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.FileTimestamp).Value = newDate
End Property

Public Property Get FileTimestamp() As Date
    FileTimestamp = this.projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.FileTimestamp).Value
End Property

Public Sub Connect(ByRef dataRow As Range)
    '--- establishes the connection of this object to the given worksheet
    '    row of project data
    Set this.projectRow = dataRow
    FindMyCheckBox
    SetCheckBoxState
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

End Sub

Private Sub FindMyCheckBox()
    '--- quickly loop through all the checkboxes on the worksheet and find the
    '    one that is located in this assigned row. there can only be one
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = this.projectRow.Parent
    For Each cb In ws.CheckBoxes
        If (cb.top >= this.projectRow.top) And _
           (cb.top < (this.projectRow.top + this.projectRow.height)) Then
            Set this.selectBox = cb
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cb
End Sub

Private Sub SetCheckBoxState()
    '--- the checkbox is enabled if there is a valid filename
    If Not this.selectBox Is Nothing Then
        If Len(Me.FullPath) > 0 Then
            this.selectBox.Enabled = True
        Else
            this.selectBox.Value = False
            this.selectBox.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

So executing the `ConnectToModel` function will create the model above.

Start interacting with the "view" by clicking any of the file browse buttons and choosing a file. The file path and timestamp are filled in. The "Name in DB" is optional and less important in this example. You can also manually enter a filename if you choose which will be picked up by the `Worksheet_Change` event in the worksheet object.

Module: `ProjectBrowse`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UserFileSelect()
    '--- connected to the "..." button on the Configure worksheet to select
    '    an MS Project file for that row
    Dim wsRow As Long
    Dim projectIndex As Long
    wsRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configure").Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
    projectIndex = ProjectRowIndex(wsRow)

    Dim pvm As ProjectsModel
    Set pvm = ConnectToModel()

    Dim projInfo As ProjectInfo
    Set projInfo = pvm.GetProject(projectIndex)

    Dim filePicker As Office.FileDialog
    Set filePicker = Application.FileDialog(MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogOpen)
    With filePicker
        .Title = "Select an MS Excel File to Add..."
        .Filters.Add "MS Project", "*.xlsx", 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If Len(projInfo.FullPath) > 0 Then
            .InitialFileName = projInfo.FullPath
        Else
            .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.path
        End If
        If .Show Then
            projInfo.FullPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Worksheet Object: `Sheet2 (Configure)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim editArea As Range
    Dim dbNameArea As Range
    Dim selectAllBox As Range
    Set editArea = ProjectGlobal.ProjectEditableArea().Columns(2)
    Set dbNameArea = ProjectGlobal.ProjectEditableArea().Columns(1)
    Set selectAllBox = ProjectGlobal.ProjectSelectAllCell()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim pvm As ProjectsModel
    Dim projectIndex As Long
    Dim projInfo As ProjectInfo
    If Not Union(editArea, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Set pvm = ProjectGlobal.ConnectToModel()
        For i = 1 To Target.Rows.Count
            projectIndex = ProjectGlobal.ProjectRowIndex(Target.Rows(i).Row)
            Set projInfo = pvm.GetProject(projectIndex)
            '--- this was just edited by the user, but re-apply the edit
            '    through the Info object for validation
            projInfo.FullPath = Target.Rows(i).Value
        Next i

    ElseIf Not Union(dbNameArea, Target) Is Nothing Then
        Set pvm = ProjectGlobal.ConnectToModel()
        For i = 1 To Target.Rows.Count
            projectIndex = ProjectGlobal.ProjectRowIndex(Target.Rows(i).Row)
            Set projInfo = pvm.GetProject(projectIndex)
            '--- this was just edited by the user, but re-apply the edit
            '    through the Info object for validation
            projInfo.NameInDB = Target.Rows(i).Value
        Next i

    ElseIf Not Union(selectAllBox, Target) Then
        ProjectSelect.CheckUncheckAll

    End If

End Sub
```

The other "view" controls are the checkboxes and the "Import" button. The code for those is below:

Module: `ProjectSelect`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CheckUncheckAll()
    Dim selectAllBox As Range
    Set selectAllBox = ProjectSelectAllCell()

    Dim pvm As ProjectsModel
    Dim projInfo As ProjectInfo
    Set pvm = ConnectToModel()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To pvm.ProjectCount
        Set projInfo = pvm.GetProject(i)
        projInfo.IsSelected = selectAllBox
    Next i
End Sub
```

Module: `ProjectImport`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ImportProjects()
    Dim pvm As ProjectsModel
    Set pvm = ConnectToModel()

    Dim selectedProjects As Collection
    Set selectedProjects = pvm.GetSelectedProjects

    Dim text As String
    If selectedProjects Is Nothing Then
        text = "No projects selected!"
    Else
        Dim proj As Variant
        For Each proj In selectedProjects
            text = text & " -- " & proj.Filename & vbCrLf
        Next proj
    End If

    MsgBox "You selected these projects for import:" & vbCrLf & text, _
           vbInformation + vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

As promised, if you wanted to create and interact with this application, import the module below and execute `BuildProjectView`

Module: `CreateProjectsSheet`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub BuildProjectView()
    '--- wipe the sheet and build it up to ensure everything is
    '    in the right place
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configure")
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        ws.Name = "Configure"
    End If
    ResetSheet ws

    Dim anchor As Range
    Dim projectArea As Range
    Dim headerArea As Range
    Dim importArea As Range
    Set anchor = ws.Range(ROW_ONE_ANCHOR)
    Set projectArea = anchor.Resize(DEFAULT_PROJECT_ROWS, ProjectInfoColumns.[_Last])
    Set headerArea = anchor.Offset(-1, 1).Resize(1, ProjectInfoColumns.[_Last] - 2)
    Set importArea = anchor.Offset(DEFAULT_PROJECT_ROWS + 1, 2)

    ws.Cells.Interior.color = XlRgbColor.rgbPaleTurquoise  'overall bg color

    FormatProjectArea projectArea, headerArea
    CreateBrowseButtons ws, projectArea
    CreateCheckboxes ws, projectArea
    CreateImportButton ws, importArea

    anchor.Offset(, 2).Select
End Sub

Private Sub ResetSheet(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    With ws
        .Cells.Clear
        .Cells.ColumnWidth = 8.14
        .Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
        .Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Cells.Font.Size = 11

        Do While .CheckBoxes.Count > 0
            .CheckBoxes(1).Delete
        Loop

        Do While .Buttons.Count > 0
            .Buttons(1).Delete
        Loop

        Do While .OLEObjects.Count > 0
            .OLEObjects(1).Delete
        Loop
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub FormatProjectArea(ByRef projectArea As Range, _
                              ByRef headerArea As Range)
    Dim areaWithoutNumbers As Range
    Set areaWithoutNumbers = projectArea.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, ProjectInfoColumns.[_Last] - 2)
    With areaWithoutNumbers.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .color = XlRgbColor.rgbDarkGray
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    '--- predefined column widths and formats
    With projectArea
        .Columns(ProjectInfoColumns.ProjectNumber).ColumnWidth = 3#
        .Columns(ProjectInfoColumns.SelectCheckBox).ColumnWidth = 3#
        .Columns(ProjectInfoColumns.DBName).ColumnWidth = 11#
        .Columns(ProjectInfoColumns.FullPath).ColumnWidth = 40#
        .Columns(ProjectInfoColumns.BrowseButton).ColumnWidth = 5#
        .Columns(ProjectInfoColumns.FileTimestamp).ColumnWidth = 14#

        .Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.SelectCheckBox).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Interior.color = rgbWhite
        .Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.DBName).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Interior.color = rgbWhite
        .Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.FullPath).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Interior.color = rgbWhite

        .Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.FileTimestamp).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"

        '--- the linked cell needs to have the same font color as the background
        .Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.SelectedCellLink).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Font.color = XlRgbColor.rgbPaleTurquoise
    End With

    With headerArea
        .Cells.Interior.color = XlRgbColor.rgbDarkBlue
        .Cells.Font.color = XlRgbColor.rgbWhite
        .Cells.Font.Bold = True
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders.color = XlRgbColor.rgbDarkGray
        .Borders.Weight = xlThin
        .WrapText = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .EntireRow.AutoFit

        Dim i As Long
        '--- start at _First+1 to skip the ProjectNumber column
        For i = (ProjectInfoColumns.[_First] + 1) To ProjectInfoColumns.[_Last]
            .Cells(1, i).Value = ProjectInfoColumnsName(i)
        Next i

        '--- the linked cell needs to have the same font color as the background
        .Cells(1, .Columns.Count + 1).Font.color = XlRgbColor.rgbPaleTurquoise
    End With

    '--- label the project indexes
    With projectArea
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            .Cells(i, ProjectInfoColumns.ProjectNumber).Value = i
        Next i
        .Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Font.Size = 8
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CreateBrowseButtons(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByRef projectArea As Range)
    Dim projectRow As Range
    Set projectRow = projectArea.Resize(1, ProjectInfoColumns.[_Last])

    Dim left As Double
    Dim top As Double
    Dim height As Double
    Dim width As Double

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To DEFAULT_PROJECT_ROWS
        With projectRow
            height = .height - 2
            width = .Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.BrowseButton).width - 2
            top = .top + 1
            left = .Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.BrowseButton).left + 1

            Dim btn As Button
            Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(left:=left, top:=top, _
                                     height:=height, width:=width)
            btn.Caption = "..."
            btn.Enabled = True
            btn.OnAction = "UserFileSelect"

            Set projectRow = projectRow.Offset(1, 0)
        End With
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub CreateCheckboxes(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByRef projectArea As Range)
    Dim projectRow As Range
    Set projectRow = projectArea.Resize(1, ProjectInfoColumns.[_Last] + 1)

    Dim left As Double
    Dim top As Double
    Dim height As Double
    Dim width As Double

    Dim cb As CheckBox
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To DEFAULT_PROJECT_ROWS
        With projectRow
            top = .top + 1
            height = .height - 2
            width = 14
            With .Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.SelectCheckBox)
                '--- centered in the column
                left = .left + (.width / 2#) - (width / 2#)
            End With
        End With
        Set cb = ws.CheckBoxes.Add(left:=left, top:=top, _
                                   height:=height, width:=width)
        cb.Caption = vbNullString
        cb.LinkedCell = projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.SelectedCellLink).Address
        projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.SelectedCellLink).Value = False

        '--- sometimes the height and width don't get correctly set during
        '    the Add call, so set them (again) here, with other settings
        cb.height = height
        cb.width = width

        Set projectRow = projectRow.Offset(1, 0)
    Next i

    '--- now add the Select All checkbox above these
    '    keep the same height, width, and left position, but
    '    recalculate the Top to set it at the botton of the cell
    Set projectRow = projectArea.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(1, ProjectInfoColumns.[_Last] + 1)
    top = projectRow.top + projectRow.height - height - 2
    Set cb = ws.CheckBoxes.Add(left:=left, top:=top, _
                               height:=height, width:=width)
    cb.Caption = vbNullString
    cb.OnAction = "CheckUncheckAll"
    cb.LinkedCell = projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.SelectedCellLink).Address
    projectRow.Cells(1, ProjectInfoColumns.SelectedCellLink).Value = False
End Sub

Private Sub CreateImportButton(ByRef ws As Worksheet, _
                               ByRef importArea As Range)
    Dim left As Double
    Dim top As Double
    Dim height As Double
    Dim width As Double

    With importArea
        height = .height * 2#
        width = .width * 2.5
        left = .left
        top = .top

        Dim btn As Button
        Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(left:=left, top:=top, _
                                 height:=height, width:=width)
        btn.Caption = "Import Select Projects"
        btn.Enabled = True
        btn.OnAction = "ImportProjects"
    End With
End Sub
```